# Youtube Layout with CSS Grid (Tailwind)

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I know your all busy, and any time you give me I value highly and would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to create a Youtube like layout with the video player, a sidebar and comments underneath the video. I'm trying to use a grid with Tailwind CSS, but the comment section (3 and 4) aren't going underneath the video player (1). This is the desktop layout I was thinking:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtgQY.png)

The order when in mobile should be video, sidebar then comments.

Heres my code so far:

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-6">
        <div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100 col-end-auto md:col-span-8" style="height: 200px;">1</div>
        <div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100 col-end-auto md:col-span-4" style="height: 400px;">2</div>
        <div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100 col-end-auto md:col-span-4">3</div>
        <div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100 col-end-auto md:col-span-4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm very great full for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you like the way everything works above mobile size (sm and up). You can add order utility classes `order-1`, `order-2` etc. to your major elements and `sm:order-none` to them as well to make sure the order only applies on mobile.

Here's an example on Tailwind Play **https://play.tailwindcss.com/RX1JQHMYgo**

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I don't think you understand, above mobile size is what doesn't work, I wondering how to get 3 and 4 slotted underneath the 1 box, instead of how they currently are, which is underneath 1 and 2.

Comment: Ahh, ok you may want to revise your question and clarify what you're looking to do. It currently reads like your mobile is out of order. Also your comment doesn't quite make sense to me. Consider adding an image of what you want it to look like.